# Patent for ideas of iOS application

Tags: ios

I am a little confused with all that stuff with patents of intellectual property in Apple developers program. There is an opinion that for IOS developing, there is no protection for unique ideas and anybody can do their applications - use any ideas(even if it was used before), BUT do not copy design and music (or any other things which are protected by copyright of their owners).
Is it true?

Comment: Can you please quote specific language from Apple's Terms of Service, or similar, to further explain your concern?

Comment: This looks correct: there is no protection for unique ideas, in iOS development or otherwise. Copyright protects designs and music. Patents protect the use of an idea in a craft, but not the idea itself, and must be applied for.